# How to asynchronize to get the data from xml file using $.ajax in jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: 'resourse/test.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    async: true,
    success: function(data){
```

I want to get the data from the xml file. So that I can store the data in the var one thread can write to the var while another on put the data in the var to a graph. How to do it. I tried several ways, but it seem the event under success stop before load the whole xml file.

Comment: Post some code and elaborate on what you've tried.  Otherwise, you're asking people to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are reading the variable outside the scope of the ajax call, so it will be called before the ajax call actually finishes.

js is asynchronous

```
$.ajax(...); //fires off
$.ajax(...); //This one will fire off before the first ajax call is finished
```

also try and step through your js code with break points and you will quickly see what happens...

Comment: Yeah! I want it to be asynchronous. But it seems the success: function event just stop and break out. It seems just one thread.I want it to continue on , and at the same time i can use the var within it.